# How do allow different elements to respond at the same time - light up multiple boxes at the same time whilst pressing multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  
  if(e.code == 'KeyB') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.batman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
    
    console.log('B clicked')
  }
  if (e.code == 'KeyS') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.spiderman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('S clicked')
  }
  if (e.code == 'KeyI') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.ironman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('I clicked')
}
  if (e.code == 'KeyT') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.thor');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('T clicked')
}
   if (e.code == 'KeyR') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.spiderman2');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('R clicked')
}
   if (e.code == 'KeyD') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.thedarkknight');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('D clicked')
}
  if (e.code == 'KeyA') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.avengers');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('A clicked')
}
   if (e.code == 'KeyW') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.wonderwoman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('W clicked')
}
    if (e.code == 'KeyP') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.spiderman3');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('P clicked')
}
}
```

```css
body {display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background:#333 url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475862013929-0af29a1197f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2534&q=80) fixed 50% 50%/ cover; }
.holo {margin:0 10px 20px 10px; xwidth:300px; xheight:200px; border:5px solid rgba(0,100,200,0.5); border-radius:20px;  text-align:center; color:rgba(0,100,200,0.9); background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); transform:scale(1.0);}

.holo:hover, .holo.active {background:rgba(30,30,30,0.8); transition-duration:0.5s; transform:scale(1.1);}


.holo h1 {font: bold 30px Arial; text-transform:uppercase;}
.holo img {width:100%; width:300px; margin:10px; border-radius:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="holo batman">
  <h1>Batman</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509347528160-9a9e33742cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
</div>

<div class="holo spiderman">
  <h1>Spiderman</h1>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521714161819-15534968fc5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
</div>
<div class="holo ironman">
  <h1>Iron Man</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509817445409-e2057fd6feac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo thor">
  <h1>Thor</h1>
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495044245703-b07f266e47b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo spiderman2">
  <h1>Spiderman 2</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505925456693-124134d66749?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo thedarkknight">
  <h1>The Dark Knight</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519740296995-10d3d8267019?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo avengers">
  <h1>Avengers</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471877325906-aee7c2240b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo wonderwoman">
  <h1>WonderWoman</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517242296655-0a451dd85b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo spiderman3">
  <h1>Spiderman 3</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534375971785-5c1826f739d8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
```

I want to be able to light up multiple boxes at the same time
whilst pressing multiple buttons - for example, pressing S, B and T at once should light up the Thor, Batman and Spiderman boxes. Right now, only two/three boxes light up/enlarge at the same time. How can I extend this? I want to make four - the whole lot respond at once if possible.

https://codepen.io/coinscrum/pen/NmJYGO

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {

  if(e.code == 'KeyB') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.batman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');

    console.log('B clicked')
  }
  if (e.code == 'KeyS') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.spiderman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');

    console.log('S clicked')
  }
  if (e.code == 'KeyM') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.ironman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');

    console.log('M clicked')
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code on codepen, and it works for me, I can enlarge Batman, Spiderman, Thor and Iron man at the same time, I'm using google chrome v73 and it works fine, what browser are you using ??

Comment: Safari - that might be why. Is there any code I can add that will ensure that it works on any browser?

Comment: I can't tell, but your code seems to be working from a user's perspective, a normal user is expected to press one or two buttons at a time, if a user wants to highlight 5 superheroes he has to press down 5 keys (not necessarily simulteanously), it is rare for a user to press 4 or 5 buttons at the same time.